# Center and horizontally align images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The form is fine I'm trying to get my social media icons to look like this picture: http://gyazo.com/1b9f9eee3c4896b73b6117638218afc5 centered, but next to each other.
[image]

http://www.bootply.com/NrHvR4fg8u Here is my form code.

Any input would be appreciated

Comment: googleLogin add float:left for this

Comment: The bootply link isn't working for me. 
Please check to make sure that the link is correct

Comment: yes same experience here. This giving error. also you should post code in question directly here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set parent div to text-align: center; and then display each social icon as inline-block.

```
#socialSignIn {
  text-align:center;
}

#socialSignIn #googleLogin, #socialSignIn #facebookLogin {
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```